# Using environment variables in windows registry

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, environment-variables

I have a game that normally saves everything to the same folder. I want to have a separate  save folder for each windows 7 account. The game's save path is stored in the windows registry. It doesn't seem to accept environment variables in the save path. Is it the game, a syntax error or are environment variables in the registry not resolved at runtime?

default

```
Save Path   REG_SZ   C:\Program Files (x86)\Diablo II\Save\
```

working with absolute path

```
Save Path   REG_EXPAND_SZ   C:\Users\account\Saved Games\Diablo II
```

not working with env variable

```
Save Path   REG_EXPAND_SZ   %USERPROFILE%\Saved Games\Diablo II
```

Note: According to a post I found on superuser REG_SZ should be changed to REG_EXPAND_SZ when using env variables. Absolute paths work either way.

Thanks!

Comment: In way way does it not "accept environment variables in the save path"?

Comment: @martineau When a save path is working the game displays saved games found there, otherwise it falls back on the default location. When I modify the registry value to %USERPROFILE%\Saved Games\Diablo II only saves from the default path are displayed. I don't know if it's the syntax, the registry or the game where it goes wrong.

Comment: Your syntax is correct. The problem seems likely due to the fact that an application has to call a specific win32 API function, [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724265%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to get the values substituted.

Comment: If the game is using `HKLM\Diablo\foo\bar\Save Path`, try setting `HKCU\Diablo\foo\bae\Save Path`. Some programs use the convention of looking there first. AFAIK, this is strictly a decision of the program (i.e., how it was designed), so some might do it while others do not.